# ggplot2 How to make axis line end at the last tick

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't want the axis lines to intersect at the origin, I also want the axis lines to start at the first tick and end at the last tick. How to do that?

Comment: You can set axis limits with [`scale_x_continuous`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) , and look at the `expand` argument.

Comment: I have it like this: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 6000, by = 1000), limits = c (0, 6000))` But the axis line still goes above and below my limits, it also intersects with xaxis

Comment: the `expand` argument...try adding `expand=c(0,0)` . You may need to tweak it slightly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ggthemes` package has tufte's rangeframe implemented. You can use `geom_rangeframe` togehter with `theme_tufte` to get a rangeframe. Then you can additionally add the scalelimits to get the axes to start at the first tick and end at the last one.

```
require(ggthemes) 
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + geom_rangeframe() + theme_tufte()

qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + 
  geom_rangeframe(data=data.frame(x=c(10, 35), y=c(0, 6)), aes(x, y)) + 
  theme_tufte() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 35)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))
```

If you don't like the theme, you can look at `theme_tufte` to get the source and change your own theme accordingly.

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + 
  geom_rangeframe(data=data.frame(x=c(10, 35), y=c(0, 6)), aes(x, y)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 35)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))
```

Alternatively, you could also just leave the axes out altogether and rely on the gridlines instead.

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 35)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(color='white'), 
        axis.ticks = element_line(color='gray90'))
```